# Связанные выпадающие списки в админке Битрикс

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

Есть два справочника в CMS Битрикс, например "Страна" и "Область" по [ISO_3166-2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2)

Старны: Россия, Великобритания, Швейцария и т.д.
Области: Россия - Амурская обл, Россия - Астраханская обл. ... Великобритания - Норт-Йоркшир, Великобритания - Бакингемшир и т.д.

Есть *инфоблок*, в атрибутах которого есть эти два справочника и в *админке битрикс* при создании или редактировании элемента выглядят как выпадающие списки.

**Внимание вопрос**: как сделать так, чтобы в *админке битрикс* в окне создания/редактирования элемента инфоблока при выборе страны список областей усекался до тех, которые относятся к данной стране?

Подобные вопросы неоднократно задавались на форуме самого битрикса, но мне не удалось нигде найти нормальный вразумительный ответ.

Единственное, что советуют и я могу сделать "легально", это при сохранении записи проверить, что была выбрана неправильная пара и не пустить дальше. Но это дико неудобно, для контент-менеджера.

На деле таких пар связанных справочников в нашей модели много, хотелось бы универсальное решение.

Пожалуйста поделитесь опытом или хотя бы подскажите, что почитать и куда копать.

Comment: Нужно для инфоблока указать кастомную страницу редактирования и собственно эту страницу редактирования создать. На этой странице исхитриться и добавить нужный js, который будет работать с change-событиями.

Comment: как альтернативный вариант, но менее красивый чем предложили выше, изменить список областей, добавить разделы страны, или приписку страны перед названием области.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно создать костомное свойство для елементов и в нем написать всю необходимую логику заполнения и сохранения свойства. Даное решение позволит не снимать с потдержки страницу редактирования елемента инфоблока и решит ваш вопрос

Пример https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/2854/blog/2193/